# Understanding colorbar dimension

Tags: prepress

I'm trying to create a ["Perfect" Colorbar](http://www.sdg-net.co.jp/products/x-rite/products_detail/pdf/Creating_the_Perfect_Colorbar.pdf). But despite my best effort, I could not make sense of the very first page:

> Press is model XYZ from vendor ABC. It is a 30-inch, four-color, offset, nonperfecting machine with 24 ink keys. The ink keys are 32 mm in width.

> If we simply divide the key width by the minimum patch size we immediately learn that we could have
> 9.143 patches (approximately) per 32 mm key. An odd number!

> Alternately, we might adjust patch width to yield an exact patch count: for example 8 patches per key! If
> we do the math; 32 mm per key divided by 8 patches per key equals **4.375 mm per patch width** - exactly.
> Will this yield a “perfect” colorbar?

How do they figure **4.375 mm** is the right dimension? Shouldn't 32 mm divided by 8 patches result in **4 mm**?

My printing ink key is 32.5 mm in width, what should be my colorbar patch size?

Comment: Maybe it's an error, a slip of the finger? As far as I know 32/8=4.  35/8=4.375

Comment: I doubt that it's a slip of the finger, as they repeat the same number in page 4. But if it truly is, then I shall know nothing more, and someone should close this thread.

Comment: I don't think you should assume errors can't be repeated throughout a document.  It's very easy to just copy and paste numbers without thinking and compound the error further. I've made similar mistakes myself.  Sorry, I'm not an mod, and can't close your question. I can only vote for closure. If you think it's unanswerable you can delete it if you want. Or perhaps just wait a while to see if someone has noticed something else which might explain it.